# Moving shapes randomly around background image in react without bumping into anything

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to react and have the following (very simple) react code which just displays a floorplan image, and two circle shapes. Here is my app.js:

```
 import map from "./map.jpeg";
    import "./App.css";
    import React from "react";
    import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
    
    const App = () => (
      <ImageBackground source={map} style={styles.image}>
        <div class="circle1 moveCircle">
          <p class="text">N</p>
        </div>
        <div class="circle2">
          <p class="text">B</p>
        </div>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      image: {
        height: "800px",
        width: "1600px",
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
```

Here is my app.css

```
.circle1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.moveCircle {
  animation-name: mymove;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;

  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
}
```

My question is, is it possible to make the two circles randomly move around the floorplan image, so it looks like people moving around? Preferably they wouldn't walk through walls or into anything.

Currently the first circle just moves to the right a little bit, then goes back to its starting position.
If anyone could give me some ideas on how to do this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Here is my image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding more keyframe selectors to your CSS. So instead of

```
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(20px);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
}
```

You can instead use something like:

```
@keyframes mymove {
  0% { transform: translateX(20px); }
  50% { transform: translateY(300px) }
  75% { transform: translateX(100px) }
  100% { transform: translateY(50px) }
}
```

If you want the movement of the circles to be even more precise, you can add as many keyframe selectors as you see fit, by breaking down the percentages to your desired amount, like this:

```
@keyframes mymove {
      0% { transform: translateX(20px); }
      10% { transform: translateX(60px); }
      20% { transform: translateY(300px) }
      30% { transform: translateX(-20px); }
      40% { transform: translateY(-100px) }
      50% { transform: translateX(20px); }
      60% { transform: translateY(50px); }
      70% { transform: translateX(20px); }
      80% { transform: translateX(60px); }
      90% { transform: translateY(20px); }
      100% { transform: translateX(-40px); }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I make them never stop moving? And the movement be random rather than me inputting a value? Thanks

Comment: animation: mymove 20s infinite;